# Stripe payment split into installment

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I am looking to integrate `stripe` payment button in to my website.

I want to charge total $40 to user, but i want to charge user in 2 installment of $20 at interval of 30 days.

e.g if a user pay now, first $20 charged now and 2nd installment of $20 will be charged after 30 days.

I studied `plans` and `subscription` document on stripe website but  its for continuous payment at particular interval.

Answer (score 3):

In Stripe docs there is a guide (or a recipe as they call it) for creating an installment plans which seems like something you need - [Creating an Installment Plan](https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/installment-plan)

They are using subscriptions and counting number of payments and then cancelling the subscription.

Comment: Here's [a direct link](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#installment-plans) to the relevant section.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It's Possible, All you have to do is Save the Card Details.

Reference : https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-save-a-card-and-charge-it-later

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will look into. I will mark it answer if its exact i needed.